# Why put size of struct in the struct?

Tags: c, api

I've for the first time begun using SetupAPI on Windows and notice that I always need to put the size of a struct into the struct before calling a function that populates the struct.  For instance:

```
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA dintf_data;
dintf_data.cbSize = sizeof(dintf_data);
SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(di, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, 0, &dintf_data);
```

What's the reason for doing that?

Is it a good way to achieve whatever it is they are trying to achieve, or are there better ways?

(The only reason I can come up with is that it's a way to deal with API versioning.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, you got it, API versioning.

The OS checks the size passed in to determine which version of the structure you are using. As features are added for newer versions of the API, fields are added (never removed), to increase the size, so the OS can know easily exactly which version you are using.

Comment: Is it a good way to do it?  What are the drawbacks?  (One obvious thing would be that it's impossible to return a struct.)

Comment: It's probably the best universal way to do it rather than having a #define with a version number for each and every struct. I can't think of any drawbacks and cannot see why you can't return a structure, at least in the sense that you pass in the structure you want filled in by the API. @djechlin - the OS checks the size passed in to determine which version of the structure you are using. As features are added for newer versions of the API, fields are added (never removed), to increase the size, so the OS can know easily exactly which version you are using.

Comment: @JimBuck I think that last sentence is right. Can you please add this to your answer though?

Comment: By return in I mean as in 'return a_struct_or_pointer_to_a_struct;', you always have to pass in a pointer and have the function populate the struct.  I'm guessing you could shrink the struct, you just must make sure that the size of the struct is unique in each version.

Most libs I've seen in the FLOSS world seem to prefer to hide details behind opaque pointers and then use accessor functions.  Hence the question.

Comment: Yeah, that's just not how the WinAPI developed over the years.. plus I think a decent API should *not* return a struct.. it should take a pointer to the struct you care about, and the return value should denote success/failure (however it's defined for the relevant API function). It also avoids a copy operation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a way of versioning to ensure backwards (and forward!) compatibility.

Imagine you've got some `struct` for a message box:

```
struct MessageBoxData {
    const char *message;
    const char *caption;
};
```

You compile this into your API and it uses this to display a message box with a `message` and a `caption`. You're fine.

Later on, you release API version 2, which adds another field for the icon displayed:

```
struct MessageBoxData {
    const char *message;
    const char *caption;
    unsigned char icon;
};
```

Let's assume the order of elements isn't magically padded or restructured by the compiler and any program may pass this more complex API version 2 struct to the API version 1 library without issues.

However, what happens the other way around? Using a program compiled against API version 1 with a library of API version 2.

The library will try to read `icon`, which will result in a read outside the valid boundaries of this `struct`!

In a similar way there might be problems if you try to copy the contents with `memcpy()` for example.

To avoid this, the Windows API typically expects the very first member to define the actual size of the struct. In this example you could create something like this:

```
// Version 1
struct MessageBoxData {
    unsigned int size;
    const char *message;
    const char *caption;
};

// Version 2
struct MessageBoxData {
    unsigned int size;
    const char *message;
    const char *caption;
    unsigned char icon;
};
```

You might think that they could just use `sizeof()` in the called function. While this is theoretically true, it won't solve the problem of different definitions between compile times (of library and program).